# How to prevent checkBox Auto change checkState After click in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

When a checkBox is clicked, how to make the checkBox doesn't change the checkState?

I want to separating response click events from variable binding in checkBox, checkBox 's checkstate only related to the variables i bind , and still respond to click events(call the click method ater click the checkbox) .

Example: if the checkBox is checked, when I click the checkBox once again, the checkBox will be still checked. It won't change the checkState,but respond to click events.I want to do this because I have setbinding code-behind for the checkBox.The checkBox'checkState only relate to the SomeBoolValue I bind.
xmal code:

```
<CheckBox Name="testCheckBox" Margin="15" Content="Test" Click="testCheckBox_Clicked"/>
```

code-behind,inside the constructor:

```
this.testCheckBox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("BoolTag") { Source = SomeBoolVariable, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
```

Add I want do something inside the click events method

```
private void testCheckBox_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Please, can you add code of what you tried? Also, please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or [How to create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What's he supposed to show though? A checkbox with a binding?

Comment: Ok,I got,I shoud add a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle uielement previewmouseleftbuttondown.

```
       <CheckBox UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CheckBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
              IsTabStop="False"
              IsChecked="{Binding SomeBool}"/>
```

In the handler, do whatever your click event needs to do and mark the event as handled.

```
    private void CheckBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do whatever you need here
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

There may be other ways to change the value so you could consider using some way to stop the ui updating that property in the viewmodel.

eg

```
    private bool someBool = true;

    public bool SomeBool
    {
        get { return someBool; }
        set {  }
    }
```

With the above you would set someBool to any new value and then raise propertychanged on SomeBool so the ui reads the changed value.

Comment: Thanks.I tried your method.But the checkBox didn't respond to click events after set IsHitTestVisible="False" ;I want to separating response click events from variable binding in checkBox, checkBox 's checkstate only related to the variables i bind ,   and still respond to click events(call the click method ater click the checkbox) .

Comment: Thank you so much.The new solution works well.That is what i want.

Comment: @曾双和  Hi, can you explain how to do that?